# Error al instalar dlib / face_recognition python

Tags: python, opencv, pip

Cuando intento instalar face_recognition me sale un error con dlib **failed building wheel for dlib**, si alguien sabe de alguna solucion (preferiblemente sin utilizar conda) que me pudiera colaborar, estoy utilizando Python 3.11.2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicionalmente estos son los paquetes que tengo instalados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No creo que pueda ayudarte a resolverlo. Pero si a que sea mas facil ayudarte. El error "failed building well..." Es simplemente un aviso de que sucedió un error. El verdadero error está lineas atras. Podrías agregar ese error en forma de texto y formateado para que el sitio lo resalte como código por favor?